# Later.js execute Function on Schedule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laterjs

I am going through the Later.js docs and it documents how to set the schedule very well - but doesn't show how to execute the function once you've done so.

So if I have

```
function logit(){
console.log('it is done');
}
```

And I want it to run once a day - Where in here do I inject logit?:

```
var cron = '15 10 * * ? *';
  var s = later.parse.cron(cron);

  later.schedule(s).next(10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the setInterval and setTimeout functions to execute code with schedule:

```
later.setInterval(logit, s);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark it solved once I see it in action at 11:30 EST :-)

Answer (score 4):

Their documentation does not make this very clear, but `later.setInterval` takes a schedule as it's second argument.

The examples for this usage are available at http://bunkat.github.io/later/execute.html

so to complete your example,

```
function logit(){
   console.log('it is done');
}

var cron = '15 10 * * ? *';
var s = later.parse.cron(cron);
later.setInterval(logit, s);
```

hope this helps.